# error during connect: The system cannot find the file specified..,the docker client must be run elevated to connect

Tags: docker, windows-10

I have installed docker on my windows 10 but when I am trying to execute any docker commands (except - v) it gives me below error. Any help ?

***error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/images/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.***